# How to check whether a folder having sub folder in android?

Tags: android, caching

I'm trying to develop an android app that could list all app's cache size and cleans the cache, cleaning of cache is working fine, but to list all the app which has cache is the problem. So I'm trying to check whether app package is having cache folder, if it exits then I'm trying to check whether cache folder is empty or not, but I'm getting force to close, I used AsyncTask too, but getting Force to close, I checked my code for plain java code, it's working, don't know what's the problem, please guide me, Thanks in Advance.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() 
            {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() 
                {
                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Loading..",
                            "Please Wait", true, false);
                }//End of onPreExecute method

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) 
                {
                    File file = new File("/data/data/com.android.browser/cache");


                    if(file.isDirectory()){

                        if(file.list().length>0){

                            System.out.println("Directory is not empty!");

                        }else{

                            System.out.println("Directory is empty!");

                        }

                    }else{

                        System.out.println("This is not a directory");

                    }

                    return null;
                }//End of doInBackground method

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) 
                {
                    pd.dismiss();

                }//End of onPostExecute method
            }.execute((Void[]) null);
        }
    });
```

There is no problem with AsyncTask I checked the code with other stuff, it's fine. Please help me in solving this riddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
     .....
 List<File> files = getListFiles(new File("YOUR ROOT")); 
 ....
 private List<File> getListFiles(File parentDir) {
    ArrayList<File> inFiles = new ArrayList<File>();
    File[] files = parentDir.listFiles();
    for (File file : files) {
        if (file.isDirectory()) {
            inFiles.addAll(getListFiles(file));
        } else {
            if(file.getName().endsWith(".csv")){
                inFiles.add(file);
            }
        }
    }
    return inFiles;
}
```